# Wpf How to change List box ItemspanelTemplate using Trigger

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemspaneltemplate

I need to set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` property of a `ListBox` based on a `DependencyProperty` on the control. How do I use the `DataTemplateSelector` to do that?

I have something like:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <!-- Here I need to replace with either a StackPanel or a wrap panel-->
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Here ([ItemsPanelTemplate Selector in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652639/itemspaneltemplate-selector-in-wpf)) is link with *Similar Question*. Below is my code but its not working:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="myXmlDataBase" XPath="/myXmlData">
            <x:XData>
                <myXmlData xmlns="">
                    <Item Name = "CoverSheet" SNo="1"  Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000003.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "HCFA" SNo="2" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000004.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "HCFA" SNo="3" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000004.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "HCFA" SNo="4" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000004.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "HCFA" SNo="5" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000004.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "HCFA" SNo="6" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000004.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "HCFA_CC" SNo="7" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\00000005.tif"/>
                    <Item Name = "FrontPage" SNo="8" Type="GrpBX" Image="C:\Work\00288511851128436163\N12201_0003_003\N12201_0003_003I00.tif"/>
                </myXmlData>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>            
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myXmlDataBase},XPath=Item}" FontSize="12" Background="LightGreen" ItemsPanel="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Background}">
             <ListBox.Resources>                    
                 <Style x:Key="ListBoxWrapStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
                     <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                 <WrapPanel Width="{Binding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
                             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Style>

                 <Style x:Key="ListBoxHorizontalStackStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
                     <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel  Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Style>

                 <Style x:Key="ListBoxVerticalStackStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
                     <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                 <StackPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" Orientation="Vertical" />
                             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Style>
             </ListBox.Resources>

             <ListBox.Style>
                 <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                         <!-- Your Trigger.. -->
                         <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Green">
                             <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxVerticalStackStyle}"/>
                         </Trigger>

                         <Trigger Property="Background" Value="LightBlue">
                             <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxHorizontalStackStyle}"/>
                         </Trigger>

                         <Trigger Property="Background" Value="LightGreen">
                             <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxWrapStyle}"/>
                         </Trigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                 </Style>
             </ListBox.Style>

             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                         <Border BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding}" BorderBrush="IndianRed"   Margin="0" Height="Auto">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Image 
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                    Width="150" Margin="5"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Height="Auto"  x:Name="Myimage" 
                                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"  Source="{Binding XPath=@Image}">
                                </Image>

                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@SNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

While running this code I'm getting **ListBoxVerticalStackStyle**'only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error say's your trying to set a `Style` when it's expecting an `ItemsPanelTemplate` as `Setter.Value`. Define your resources as `ItemPanelTemplate`'s than `ListBox` `Style`'s and you should be sorted

Try something like:

```
<ListBox Name="lv"
          Background="LightBlue"
          FontSize="12"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myXmlDataBase},
                                XPath=Item}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ListBoxWrapTemplate">
      <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                  ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                  ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ListBoxHorizontalStackTemplate">    
      <StackPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                  Orientation="Horizontal" />    
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ListBoxVerticalStackTemplate">
      <StackPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                  Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <!--  Your Trigger..  -->
        <Trigger Property="Background"
                  Value="Green">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel"
                  Value="{DynamicResource ListBoxVerticalStackTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Background"
                  Value="LightBlue">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel"
                  Value="{DynamicResource ListBoxHorizontalStackTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Background"
                  Value="LightGreen">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel"
                  Value="{DynamicResource ListBoxWrapTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Style>
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot working Perfectly Fine and moreover i have changed **StaticResource** ratherthan **DynamicResource** and i'm stuck with one more issue when it aplies **ListBoxWrapTemplate** Actually images are not getting Wrapped instead its aligned Horzontally with **HorizontalScroll bar**.I don't want this **HorizontalScroll bar** but Images has to be Wrapped.

Comment: Is there any correction with the design to work **ListBoxWraptemplate** ?? please guide. Thanx.

Comment: @Selva I think that's because the `WrapPanel`'s Width does not force it to "wrap" as a quick guess try setting `Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"` on the `WrapPanel`

Comment: Problem is with **ViewBox Stretch="Fill"** if i give **Stretch="None"** its working perfectly well. but i could'n figure out the root cause for this issue. May be it could be due to **LayoutTransform** because if i give **Stretch = Fill** the every image is taking the whole width of the **ListBox** .Do u have any idea behind this? .Thans a lot for ur reply.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering why Viv's answer did not work in my case :-(
Here is what I did wrong:

Do not define the ItemsPanelTemplate appart from the `<Style.Triggers>` !
If you place one in the `<Listbox.ItemPanel></Listbox.ItemPanel>` the style triggers won't have any effect.

Arnaud.

ps: no sufficient reputation to only comment...